# Add rows to pandas dataframe with new column - extend the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have a DatFrame like this:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

And I want to apply a function to it so that each row will be duplicated and a new column will be added. The value in the new column is 'a' and 'b' for created duplicate rows for even valued col1 and 'c' and 'd' for odd valued col1.

So the desired output is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | c |
| 1 | 3 | d |
| 2 | 4 | a |
| 2 | 4 | b |

I have tried to solve this plainly by iterating over all rows and got what I want,
but as far as I know `iterrows()` is extremely slow if we have hundreds of thousands of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def add_rows(row):
    """
    This function is used in apply function. It adds a new column and adds rows to the dataframe.
    :param row:
    :return:
    """
    col3 = np.array(['a', 'b'])
    out_df = pd.DataFrame([row.tolist()], columns=row.index)
    out_df['col3'] = None
    if row['col1'] % 2 == 0:
        out_df.at[0, 'col3'] = col3
    else:
        out_df.at[0, 'col3'] = np.array(['c', 'd'])
    out = out_df.explode('col3', ignore_index=True)
    return out

cols = list(df.columns)
cols.append('col3')
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    rows = add_rows(row)
    result = pd.concat([result, rows])
result.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(result)
```

And my data has hundreds of thousands of rows and thousands of columns.
Can this be achieved in a better way?
I have tried to `apply` this function but got some weird output.
Maybe apply needs to return something different than a data frame for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.apply` to check if the value in `col1` is even/odd, assign the required list and `.explode` afterwards:

```py
df["col3"] = df.apply(lambda x: ["c", "d"] if x["col1"] % 2 else ["a", "b"], axis=1)
df = df.explode("col3")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     3    c
0     1     3    d
1     2     4    a
1     2     4    b
```